# How can I get image file name from AssetImage in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am displaying couple of images on first page using Image.asset . Idea is, when I click on one image, I should be able get the image name, so that I can send to next page and display the image with its detail. I am getting image in AssetImage format like

```
AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "images/image1.png")
```

How can I just extract the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve it by assigning the image name on a string

```
String img1 = "image1";
```

and use String concatenation operator to produces the image path

```
Image.asset('images/$img1.png')
```

and then you can pass the image name to a constructor.

Answer (score 3):

You have to store image names in a list. And on tap image, you can access the image name from the list using index. Its the easiest solution to me.

Or in case you want to extract the name from assetImagePath, than...
You can use RegEx, No extra package required :)

```
  String path = 'images/image1.png';
  RegExp exp = RegExp('\/((?:.(?!\/))+\$)');
  String fileName = exp.firstMatch(path).group(1);
  print(fileName); // image1.png
```

Test the Code here: https://dartpad.dev/

Answer (score 1):

First You have to make a clickable AssetImage using below code:

```
Material(
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
    var imgName = "images/image1.png"
      **<< Pass image name as per your requirement >>**
     },
    child: Container(
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        child: Image.asset('images/image1.png',
            width: 110.0, height: 110.0),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [path library](https://pub.dev/documentation/path/latest/path/path-library.html)'s function, called `basename` ([see docs here](https://pub.dev/documentation/path/latest/path/basename.html))

For example:

```
File fileLocation = new File("/dir1/dir2/image.png"); // Here's the location of the image
String imageName = basename(fileLocation.path);
print(imageName); // The output should be => image.png
```

Don't forget to import the packages:

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';
```